# ManyToManyField in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I need to create a set of models like this:

```
class Step(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Scenario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    steps = models.ManyToManyField(Step, related_name="scenarios")
```

The thing is I want the scenario to include several steps in an order that I will specify and even the same step several times. Like this:

```
Scenario1:
    step1
    step2
    step1
    step3
```

I want this step's order to be easy editable in admin site.
I found out about `filter_horizontal`, it looks a lot like what I need in admin site, but it has no option to add a step one more time and to move steps up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a saying in computer science that says that: "*All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of [indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection)*" - David Wheeler.

In that case you should use a "through" table, like:

```
class Step(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Scenario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    steps = models.ManyToManyField(
        Step,
        through='ScenarioStep',
        related_name="scenarios"
    )

class ScenarioStep(models.Model):
    scenario = models.ForeignKey(
        'Scenario',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='scenariostep'
    )
    step = models.ForeignKey(
        'Step'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='scenariostep'
    )
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

Here we thus introduce an extra model that replaces the hidden "through table" that was already constructed by the `ManyToManyField`.

A `Scenario` thus has a `Step`, given there is a `ScenarioStep` record, and we order this by an `Order` field.

We can, for example, add the given steps to the `scenario` with:

```
s1 = Step.objects.create(field1='step1')
s2 = Step.objects.create(field1='step1')
s3 = Step.objects.create(field1='step1')

sc1 = Scenario.objects.create(name='Scenario1')

ScenarioStep.objects.create(order=1, scenario=sc1, step=s1)
ScenarioStep.objects.create(order=2, scenario=sc1, step=s2)
ScenarioStep.objects.create(order=3, scenario=sc1, step=s1)
ScenarioStep.objects.create(order=4, scenario=sc1, step=s3)
```

We can then iterate over the steps with:

```
for step in sc1.steps.order_by('scenariostep'):
    # ... (do something with the step)
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is it. The one thing left is how to make editing scenarios easier (moving commands up and down and filling order with right value automatically). Could you advise what should I look for? For now I am using `TabularInline` class.